# Apache proxy url to port

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have `RStudio` server running on my computer. I can access it in the following url:

```
http://localhost:8787/
```

or my .com

```
http://mysecreturl.com:8787/
```

I would like to configure apache so I can use

```
http://localhost/Rstudio
```

or

```
 http://mysecreturl.com/Rstudio
```

I created the following file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/Rstudio`

```
    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Proxy>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPass /Rstudio http://localhost:8787
    ProxyPassReverse /Rstudio https://localhost:8787
```

and restarted apache `service apache2 restart`

But is not working.

Thanks for the help!

---

I think this is the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it

> $ sudo a2enmod mod_proxy mod_proxy_http mod_ssl
>   ERROR: Module mod_proxy does not exist!
>   ERROR: Module mod_proxy_http does not exist!
>   ERROR: Module mod_ssl does not exist!

I'm on ubuntu 15.04

Comment: I summon the power of ServerFault... http://serverfault.com/questions/472482/proxypass-redirect-directory-url-to-non-standard-port (refer to the answer)

Comment: That is the post I read to try to make this work. Not sure what am I doing wrong... :(

Comment: have you make sure that all the apache module is installed properly?

Comment: I added some more information. I think the modules are the problem, but i don't know how to load them

Comment: What about "sudo a2enmod proxy_http"?

Comment: $ sudo a2enmod proxy_http
Considering dependency proxy for proxy_http:
Module proxy already enabled
Module proxy_http already enabled

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78642/discussion-between-ignacio-and-fariz-luqman).

Comment: try moving the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/Rstudio to /etc/apache2/**sites-enabled**/Rstudio or else your configuration file will not be activated/used